# Why can't Bloomberg Api (blp) catch the data by correct field id?

Tags: python, bloomberg

I want to use python to catch the "ESG disclosure score " data in Bloomberg. It is my sample code :

```
from xbbg import blp
#1
blp.bdp(tickers='AAPL US Equity', flds=['Security_Name', 'GICS_Sector_Name','PX_last', 'HISTORICAL_MARKET_CAP'])

#2
blp.bdh(
   ...:     tickers='AAPL US Equity', flds=['Security_Name','HISTORICAL_MARKET_CAP','ESG_DISCLOSURE_SCORE'],
   ...:     start_date='2010-1-1', end_date='2020-12-31',
   ...: )
```

First code can be executed correctly. The output is like this:

[image: Output 1]

But the second one is wrong, like this:

[image: Output 2]

The columns of "ESG disclosure score" disappear! It seems like it can't catch the data from Bloomberg. I make sure the flds for ESG disclosure score is correct!

Cany somebody help me or suggest me for solving this ?problem ?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you asked the help desk? Have you tried in Excel? I don't have the terminal in front of me but it's possible that that field doesn't allow historical queries.

Comment: Notice that you are not getting a historical series for ‘Security_Name’ either, even though you asked for it …

Comment: @assylias thank you for replying me! I asked the help desk, they want me to try another way, it constrained because Bloomberg terminal is bought from school. So, I think the function is not enough to do that. By the way, the historical data of ESG disclosure score is available.

Comment: @DS_London thank you for reminding. I almost didn't notice it.

Comment: When it comes to ESG in general, Bloomberg seems to be restricting some data to BQL() queries in Excel. In the Terminal, type 'BQLX', then click on 'BQL for ESG'.

Answer (score 3):

**The Bloomi Terminal FLDS function should be the first port of call** for any questions about the fields that might be available, their format, and any possible overrides. In a Terminal window, type:

```
AAPL US <Equity Yellow Key> FLDS <Go>
```

Where it says "Enter Query" type `ESG_DISCLOSURE_SCORE` and hit 'Go'. If you click on the returned match, you get this screen:
[image]

If you scroll down the text, you see:

```
API:
current value available, historical values available
```

*So this field does, in general, provide history via `bdh` and `bdp`*. The `API` (sometimes called DAPI by Bloomberg) is usually what Excel, xbbg, or client-based code is using to get data from Bloomberg. If you can't see the data in this screen, you can't get it via xbbg.

BUT, look at the current value for ESG_DISCLOSURE_SCORE for this security: it is `N.A`. That means that while the field exists, *it has not been populated for `AAPL`*. The text description of the field gives more information.

A feature of `xbbg` is that if a historical field has no data then it is not included in the returned dataframe of `bdh` at all (not even as a column of nan). That is why your dataframe does not have a 'ESG_DISCLOSURE_SCORE' column.

Comment: Thank you for answering me. I can get the current ESG disclosure score for "AMZN US Equity", but still can't get the historical data (even though I see the historical data in Terminal). It seem that blp.bdp function can work, but blp.bdh can not work for this.

Comment: @Yuan-ChunLin "even though I see the historical data in Terminal" ... how do you see this data? I don't see any actual historical values for AMZN US Equity. In the Terminal, type `AMZN US Equity GP Go`, and  if you change the dropdown 'Last Px' to 'ESG Disc Score' you will get the message: 'There is no available data for the currently loaded security'.